# Finding number of zeros in the end in n!

Tags: c++, c, factorial

Is there any efficient method to compute the number of zeros at the end of n! without explicitly needing to calculate n!?

Comment: This has been discussed in math.stackexchange: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/number-of-zeros-at-the-end-of-a-factorial

Comment: by table lookup: `unsigned nzeros[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6}; /* ... */`

Comment: @pmg: hmm, makes you wonder why programming languages even bother supporting arithmetic. We could just look everything up ;-p

Comment: @Steve: I think pmg's point was that `n!` does not fit in any native types except for tiny values of `n`. What pmg is missing, and the whole thing that makes this problem interesting, is that the number of trailing zeros **does** fit in small types, and is very easy to compute without computing `n!`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is. Key ideas: (1) it's the same as the highest power of 5 that divides n!; (2) that's the number of multiples of 5 up to n, plus the number of multiples of 25 up to n, plus the number of multiples of 125 up to n, etc.

But this doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

The number of zeros at the end of N! is given by

∑ floor( n/5<sup>i</sup> )  for i = 1,2,3....

Simple code in C

```
    i = 1, sum = 0;
    while(pow(5,i)<= n)
    {
        sum += n/(pow(5,i));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The number of zeros in the decimal representation of n! is the number of times ten appears as a factor of that large number.  Hence, the number of times 2x5 appears.  Hence, as there will be many more occurrences of 2 as a factor than of 5 (why?), it is the number of times 5 is a factor of n!.

So, your interview question is: how many fives appear as factors of items in the expression

```
1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7 x 8 x 9 x 10 x ... x (n-1) x n
```

?